# Can Sqoop Perform any ETL Related Tasks while it Imports?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, hdfs, sqoop

Currently, as I understand it, data is to be Sqooped into HDFS from a relational database. From there, Pig or M/R can run ETL related tasks, and put the transformed data into another part of the HDFS. The original data can then be deleted if necessary.

Is there a way to avoid importing the original data into HDFS and run PIG and M/R on the data as it is coming in through Sqoop? How is this done?

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop/Pig/Hive/MR are batch oriented (long time) in nature and can't process the data in real time. Consider using frameworks like [Flume](http://flume.apache.org/) / [Storm](http://storm-project.net/) / [Samza](http://samza.incubator.apache.org/) / [S4](http://incubator.apache.org/s4/)